# Did John Earle Sullivan invite Proud Boys on stage at a rally and said he wants to work with them?

Tags: united-states, quotes

The Salt Lake Tribune [writes](https://www.sltrib.com/news/politics/2021/01/16/robert-gehrke-what-we/) (Jan 16) about John Earle Sullivan:

> In June 2020, John attended his first Black Lives Matter event, according to Lex Scott, the founder of the Utah chapter of the group. Nobody had seen him before or knew who he was. Sullivan also started his own group, Insurgence USA, in response to the killing of George Floyd and he organized his first protest in Provo. [...]
>
> **“At his second protest he invited the Proud Boys on stage, he invited the militias on stage and said, ‘We want to work with you, we want to be friends with you,’”** Scott said. “That is when he officially got blackballed by the activist community.”
>
> Scott said Sullivan never attended any of the BLM meetings, never worked on any of their initiatives, never helped with their push for police reform.
>
> “This guy is a clout-chaser, someone who is only here for fame or money or someone who just needs attention,” she said. “He’s a thorn in my side.”

There are some reasons to be a bit skeptical of this claim: Scott may see Sullivan as competition at least, and perhaps *now* wants to discredit him for other reasons, in particular after Sullivan took part in the storming of the Capitol and was [charged](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/50177/29579) for it.

So, is there more evidence (besides this claim from Scott) that Sullivan did invite Proud Boys on stage at some earlier rally and said on that occasion he wanted to "work with" them?

(Unfortunately, the article does not make clear when or where this 2nd rally of Sullivan took place. Answers will have to deal with that as well.)

Comment: This article says after Sullivan's protestors arrived at the Utah state capitol initially intending to be against white militia, the "Utah Constitutional Militia" reached out to Sullivan and they found common ground and had a peaceful armed protest there together. https://ksltv.com/444431/protestors-march-to-state-capitol-armed-with-guns/ So I think Scout is calling "Utah Contitutional Militia" the name "Proud Boys".

Comment: Also, from his "InsurgenceUSA" and "Jayden X" twitter accounts, Sullivan on 1/3/2021 posted a video of "Proud Boys Burn Blue Lives Matter Flag" and from 1/1 to 1/3 he tweeted other stuff about left and right working together against the police.

Comment: https://twitter.com/realjaydenx/status/1345857796336566272

Comment: @DavePhD: hmm, it looks the claim (I've inquired about) may be more figurative than actually true. It seems *his brother* James was at some [shared talk](https://www.alamy.com/portland-oregon-usa-26th-september-2020-james-sullivan-of-civilized-awakening-speaks-during-proud-boys-end-to-domestic-terrorism-rally-in-support-of-kenosha-shooter-kyle-rittenhouse-and-aaron-jay-danielson-who-was-shot-dead-by-an-antifascist-protester-during-the-ongoing-black-lives-matter-protests-in-the-city-credit-albert-halimalamy-live-news-image376844197.html) with Proud Boys. So maybe someone blurred the distinction