# Did "Antifa in Portland" issue an "anonymous tip" in Nov that John E. Sullivan be “locked out” of their circles because he is "agent provocateur"?

Tags: united-states, quotes

A Jan 15 OpIndia [article](https://www.opindia.com/2021/01/john-sullivan-storming-of-capitol-hill-fbi-donald-trump-antifa-blm/) says:

> On the 23rd of November 2020, Antifa in Portland is said to have issued an ‘anonymous tip’ demanding that John Sullivan be “locked out” of their circles. “While it’s easier, and generally more fair, to believe he is a naive narcissist, clout chaser and inept organizer, it might not be an accurate analysis. A narc for the feds might not be an accurate assessment either. It’s more likely that John is an agent provocateur, putting activist communities in danger.”

Is there any verification of this claim, that "Antifa in Portland" issued that statement... anonymously?

Comment: I'm guessing "Antifa in Portland" refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_City_Antifa but not sure...

Comment: There's a lot of groups in Portland who identify as Antifa. I am immediately suspicious of any article referring to BLM or Antifa as a single organization.

Comment: @Schwern In the case of BLM, it's complicated a bit by the fact that there actually is a particular 'main' organization (i.e. [Black Lives Matter Global Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lives_Matter_Global_Network_Foundation)) in addition to the broader movement, much or most of which isn't directly affiliated with that organization. So, sometimes the term actually is used to refer to a particular organization and sometimes it isn't and speakers/writers often don't specify which they mean.

Comment: @reirab It's not complicated, which is why it's suspicious when folks get it wrong. If you mean an organization, or an officer of that org, you specify that. If you mean an individual member, you specify that. If you mean someone who identifies with a movement, you specify that. It's the difference between "Republicans in Portland say basset hounds got long ears" and "Joe Smith, a registered Republican residing in Portland, says basset hounds got long ears" and "Republicans For Basset Hounds, a non-profit based in Portland, issued a press release stating basset hounds got long ears".

Comment: @Schwern I was using "complicated" as the past tense of a verb, not as an adjective. Agreed that it's usually not that hard to report it correctly (assuming that you know or can reasonably find out whether something was done by a group of people who happen to identify with the BLM movement or by people actually affiliated with the BLM organization.) Unfortunately, however, most journalists seem to be lazy (or worse, intentionally misleading/sensationalizing) and don't specify which meaning of "BLM" they're using.

Comment: @Schwern Agreed that your analogy is apt, though, really, journalists frequently do the same sort of thing with those cases. They'll frequently say something like "Portland Republicans" said or did x without specifying whether they mean "some people who consider themselves Republicans and happen to live in Portland" or "the Republican Party of Portland." And, of course, they do the same with Democrats and even worse with Libertarians/libertarians, where libertarians (people who hold libertarian ideologies) frequently don't identify as Libertarians (members of the Libertarian Party.)

Comment: Since we do not have a John Sullivan tag, related questions include https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/was-john-earle-sullivan-at-the-capitol-riot and https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50182/was-the-storming-of-the-us-capitol-orchestrated-by-antifa-and-blm-organisers and https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50194/did-john-earle-sullivan-invite-proud-boys-on-stage-at-a-rally-and-said-he-wants

Comment: So many issues with the claim that it borders on nonsense.  The problem starts with Antifa not even being a _thing_ (organizationally speaking), and ends somewhere around the suggestion that a non-entity can have "circles" or the ability to lock people out of those non-existent circles.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Let's clarify, there's no "Antifa in Portland" organization. There's a lot of groups who identify as Antifa in the City of Portland, Oregon, and a lot of groups who don't but are labelled Antifa anyway. Anyone can claim to be Antifa. Antifa is short for Anti-Fascist, and refers to an activist stance rather than a specific organization.

***Yes he was identified as a problem in November 2020***. [A thread on the @RebellionBaby Twitter account on Nov 26, 2020](https://twitter.com/RebellionBaby/status/1331902008765206528) covers John Sullivan. Here's the beginning.

> We have reason to believe that a likely infiltrator/agent provocateur by the name of John Sullivan, or “Activist John,” is attempting to insert himself in the Seattle protest community.
>
> John has been kicked from the #SaltLakeCity and #Portland protest scenes due to alarming behaviors including grifting/profiteering, self-promotion/clout chasing, sabotage of community actions, threats of violence, and — maybe most disturbingly — ties to the far-right.
>
> In short — John’s brother, James, is the co-founder of a pro-Trump org called “Civilized Awakening,” and has strong ties to Proud Boys — even having spoken at a Proud Boy rally. The brothers’ polarized political stances conveniently bolster the other's public personas.

In that thread they [share a "document from a PDX comrade"](https://twitter.com/RebellionBaby/status/1331902025429258241) (PDX being the airport code for Portland International Airport and a common abbreviation for Portland, Oregon) dated Nov 23rd, 2020 entitled "Anonymous Tip #1 From PDX. John Sullivan: Naive Organizer or Agent Provocateur?" which contains the quote.

> After seeing a lot of posts about John Sullivan, AKA Activist John, I felt compelled to write up my personal experience and observations as well as share some of the research I found to help make better sense of the situation for the good and safety of our community and work.
>
> If you don't have the time to read the whole piece, here's the big takeaway:
>
> ***While it's easy, and generally more fair, to believe he is a naive narcissist, clout chaser, and inept organizer, it might not be an accurate analysis. A narc for the Feds might not bee an accurate assessment either. It's more likely that John is an agent provocateur, putting protesting communities in danger.***

The document goes on to make their case.

[@RebellionBaby had a long update thread on Jan 14th, 2021](https://twitter.com/RebellionBaby/status/1349717938803142656). Here's the beginning.

> John Sullivan / “#ActivistJohn” / "#JaydenX" Update
>
> Our first thread about John was intended to help protect leftist protest communities from his harmful behavior. Since John’s little stunt at the Capitol during the DC #Insurrection, we have more to talk about.
>
> ...
>
> General Updates:
>
> Shortly after our 11/26 thread, Seattle protesters made it clear that John is not welcome at our actions or in our online spaces. He later changed his main account names from “Activist X” and “Activist John” to “Activist Jayden” and “Jayden X.”

Comment: That 1st thread at one point links to https://twitter.com/RebellionBaby/status/1331902025429258241/photo/2 which is titled "An anonymous tip #1 from PDX". That may be what's alluded to.

Comment: @Fizz That would seem to be it.

Comment: The actual author of that piece is Papa "Queen Antifa" Gila, who restricts direct access to [their tweets](https://twitter.com/protestpapi/status/1330595392350666752), but you can circumvent that easily enough with Google's cache. They seem to have tweeted all those 4 (img) pages in a long series of tweets, often with mid-sentence breaks.